# Making a normal form as MDI

Tags: vb.net, user-interface

I am working on a application in which I have to show different forms stacked one upon the other. Due to some restrictions, I cannot use MDI and also it has a lot of issues.

I am able to get what I want but with a problem. The forms will be stacked, but they do not remain in the parent form. 
Lets take it by an example.  The structure goes like this. 
1) There is a form A (My parent form)
2) a second form "B" opens on a button click event on Form "A". (Note: B.ShowInTaskBar=False)
3) again, a third form "C" opens on a button click event on Form "B". (Note: C.ShowInTaskBar=False)

Now, when I minimize form A, it gets minimized but the Form B and C, remains as it is. I want them to get minimized at the same time. I want form B and C should remain as a child form of form A.

How to get that.

Comment: What restrictions disallow the use of MDI forms? Trying to reinvent MDI forms on your own seems unnecessary.

Comment: 1) the forms B and C has to be like FormborderStyle=None. 
2) I cannot show the stack of forms one over the other. While opened, their sizes would be some thing like this.
B.Size= A.Size - 40
C.Size= B.Size -40

Comment: A UI gadget that has no border and needs to stay inside its parent is better known as a UserControl.  A TabControl is handy to allow the user to switch between them.

Answer (score 3):

Just use MDI forms. There is no technical restriction about `FormBorderStyle`'s value for MDI children. Remember to set the [IsMdiContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.ismdicontainer.aspx) property to `true` for the parent form and then set the child form's [MdiParent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.mdiparent.aspx) property to the parent form before `Show()` is called.

**Edit:**
I'm not exactly sure what you mean by stacking. You can easily control the child positions if that is what you mean:

```
public void ShowChildren()
{
    Child child1 = new Child();
    Child child2 = new Child();

    child1.MdiParent = this;
    child2.MdiParent = this;

    child1.Show();
    child2.Show();

    child1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 100);
    child1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
    child2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 100);
    child2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 100);
}
```

**Edit #2:**
Are you trying to nest the forms? If so you can make the parent a normal form and place a `UserControl` A in the parent. Then place `UserControl` B in `UserControl` A. Allowing the user to move these around becomes more difficult, but if you already wanted no border this may not be an issue for you.

Comment: I am not able to stack the others forms when I use MDI.

Comment: This will not restrict the third form on the second one. 
My third form should be always on top of second, which should be on the first. 

Also, only the topmost form should be click-able. 
Thanks for trying Mike.

Answer (score -1):

```
public void formMain_buttonShowA_click() {
    FormA formA = new FormA();
    formA.ShowDialog();
}

public void formA_buttonShowB_click() {
   FormB formB = new FormB();
   formB.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: This answer contains only code, and while it may answer the "what to do" part of the question, it doesn't elaborate on "why, how and when" to use this solution. If you have time and desire, then, please, add some explanation to your post - high-quality posts with both the code and explanation with references are far more useful and are usually being upvoted more often. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for more tips.

Comment: Also, are you sure that your code will help in such situations? Each form will create new another form, that in its turn will create new first form, so I am not sure that it will help in OP's situation.